# ¿Es posible crear una columna virtual para un modelo para una consulta join en RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Realmente estuve pensando en como titular la pregunta y esto fue lo que mejor se me ocurrió.

Tengo el siguiente problema:

1.- Creé un método que me trae los tipos de tela de cada ropa, en el modelo ropa tengo esto:

```
def tipo_de_tela
    Tela.where("id = #{self.tela_id}").first.nombre if self.tela_id
end
```

al llamarlo desde la consola, me trae el tipo de tela.

```
irb(main):004:0> ropa = Ropa.find(2)
  Ropa Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "ropas".* FROM "ropas" WHERE "ropas"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Ropa id: 2, nombre: "camisa", created_at: "2019-09-06 12:47:41", updated_at: "2019-09-06 12:47:41", tela_id: 2>
irb(main):005:0> ropa.tipo_de_tela
  Tela Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "telas".* FROM "telas" WHERE (id = 2) ORDER BY "telas"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> "seda"
```

Al hacer una consulta join en el modelo de maestros, para esa misma ropa:

```
def self.trae_uno(m_id)
    self.
        select("maestros.id, ropas.nombre ropa, ropas.tipo_de_tela, colors.nombre color")
        .joins(:ropa, :color)
        .where(id: m_id)
end
```

*Donde m_id = 2*

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  no existe la columna ropas.tipo_de_tela
LINE 1: SELECT  maestros.id, ropas.nombre ropa, ropas.tipo_de_tela, ...
                                                ^
: SELECT  maestros.id, ropas.nombre ropa, ropas.tipo_de_tela, colors.nombre color FROM "maestros" INNER JOIN "ropas" ON "ropas"."id" = "maestros"."ropa_id" INNER JOIN "colors" ON "colors"."id" = "maestros"."color_id" WHERE "maestros"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2):
```

¿Alguna idea de como puedo salir de este atolladero?

Comment: Te recomiendo agregar `Tela` al `joins` en `Maestros`; ¿qué relación hay entre `Tela` y `Maestros`?

Comment: Si ya lo había probado y funciona, solo que quería saber si se podía hacer una consulta sin tantos joins,... una pregunta relacionada con esta pregunta o derivada de esta pregunta, ¿se puede renombrar una consulta join, con el formato de active_record? me refiero a algo como esto, que se que no funciona, pero he buscado y no he encontrado nada. .joins(:ropa as 'r', :color as 'c')

Comment: No hay relación entre el modelo maestros y tela, pero si hay relación entre telas y ropa, tela belongs to ropa, ropa has many telas.

Comment: Hasta donde sé no puedes renombrar una consulta con `joins`. Con respecto a utilizar _tantos joins_, generalmente es mejor hacerlos en la base de datos (está optimizada para eso) que en tu aplicación. De una u otra forma necesitarás hacer ese `join`. Aunque **Rails** te permitiera hacer algo similar a lo que buscas, sería simplemente decorar los `joins`.